# Split date ranges into multiple date ranges in TSQL

Tags: date, t-sql, range, sql-view

I'm trying to combine two date ranges.

Here are the input data:

```
drop table if exists #ranges
create table #ranges (caseId int not null, startDate date  not null, endDate date not null, Employee VARCHAR(50))

insert #ranges select 1, '2023-01-01', '2023-12-31','ABc'
insert #ranges select 1, '2023-01-15', '2023-05-01', 'CBa'

insert #ranges select 2, '2023-01-01', '2023-05-01', 'ABc'
insert #ranges select 2, '2023-01-15', '2023-03-01', 'DEf'
insert #ranges select 2, '2023-02-01', '2023-12-31', 'GHi'
```

What I need is this result:

```
drop table if exists #result
create table #result (caseId int not null, startDate date  not null, endDate date not null, Employee VARCHAR(50))
insert #result select 1, '2023-01-01', '2023-01-14','ABc'
insert #result select 1, '2023-01-15', '2023-05-01', 'CBa'
insert #result select 1, '2023-05-02', '2023-12-31','ABc'

insert #result select 2, '2023-01-01', '2023-01-14','ABc'
insert #result select 2, '2023-01-15', '2023-03-01', 'DEf'
insert #result select 2, '2023-03-02', '2023-05-01','ABc'
insert #result select 2, '2023-05-02', '2023-12-31','GHi'
```

The goal is to define a valid time slot for each employee.
I would prefer this query in a SQL-View but a stored procedure is also ok.

Hope someone can help me.

I tried to achieve the goal with common table expression but have problems to create the 3. row.

Comment: Will you have multiple overlapping date ranges ? or how about other scenario like partial overlapping ? Please edit your question to include all possible scenarios

Comment: Also your title is the opposite of what you want. You want to split into multiple date range and not combine

Comment: I changed the title.

Comment: And added one more case (with overlaps and partial overlap)

Comment: basically both your case are the same. the last row of `case 2` is standalone and does not overlap any other date at all

Comment: case 1 and 2 should cover my needs :)

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe the ugliest SQL I have written, and I am fairly confident there are other better ways to do it. The approach I took is this

1. Create the digits 0 - 9
2. Create integers using the digits
3. Grab just the dates of interest (I did it one case at a time)
4. Find the min and max dates from step 3
5. Create a list of all dates from the min to the max found in step 4
6. Find possible employees for each day
7. Rank the possible employees for each day using the employee with the smallest stretch of days
8. Take the single employee for each day
9. Start transforming back to groups for listing purposes
10. Complete transforming into groups

And finally display the output. I almost didn't post this because it is a mess and I know someone will have a better answer, but assuming an answer is better than no answer, here you go:

For case 1:

```sql
drop table if exists #ranges
create table #ranges (caseId int not null, startDate date  not null, endDate date not null, Employee VARCHAR(50))

insert #ranges select 1, '2023-01-01', '2023-12-31','ABc'
insert #ranges select 1, '2023-01-15', '2023-05-01', 'CBa'

insert #ranges select 2, '2023-01-01', '2023-05-01', 'ABc'
insert #ranges select 2, '2023-01-15', '2023-03-01', 'DEf'
insert #ranges select 2, '2023-02-01', '2023-12-31', 'GHi'

;WITH digits AS (
    SELECT I FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) AS digits(I)
), integers AS (
    SELECT D1.I + 10 * D2.I + 100*D3.I + 1000*D4.I + 10000*D5.I AS I
    FROM [digits] AS D1 CROSS JOIN [digits] AS D2 CROSS JOIN [digits] AS D3 
    CROSS JOIN [digits] AS D4 CROSS JOIN [digits] AS D5
), all_employee_dates AS (
    SELECT [startDate] AS d, [Employee] FROM [#ranges] WHERE [caseId] = 1
    UNION 
    SELECT [EndDate] AS d, [Employee] FROM [#ranges] WHERE [caseId] = 1
), min_and_max_dates AS (
    SELECT MIN(d) AS min_date, MAX(d) AS max_date FROM all_employee_dates 
), [days] AS (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, integers.I, [min_and_max_dates].[min_date]) AS d
    FROM [min_and_max_dates] CROSS JOIN [integers] 
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, integers.I, [min_and_max_dates].[min_date]) <= [min_and_max_dates].[max_date]
), calendar AS (
    SELECT [d].[d], [r].[caseId], [r].[startDate], [r].[endDate], [r].[Employee], 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, r.[startDate], r.[endDate]) AS [days]
    FROM [days] AS d
    INNER JOIN [#ranges] AS r ON d.[d] BETWEEN r.[startDate] AND r.[endDate] AND r.[caseId] = 1
), prioritized_calendar AS ( 
    SELECT [calendar].[d],
           [calendar].[caseId],
           [calendar].[startDate],
           [calendar].[endDate],
           [calendar].[Employee],
           [calendar].[days], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [calendar].[d] ORDER BY [calendar].[days]) AS rn 
    FROM [calendar] 
), assigned_days AS (
    SELECT [prioritized_calendar].[d], [prioritized_calendar].[Employee]
    FROM [prioritized_calendar] 
    WHERE rn = 1 
), groups_assigned_days AS (
    SELECT [assigned_days].[d], [assigned_days].[Employee], 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [assigned_days].[Employee] ORDER BY [assigned_days].[d]), [assigned_days].[d]) AS g
    FROM [assigned_days] 
), compact_groups AS (
    SELECT MIN([groups_assigned_days].d) AS [start_date], MAX([groups_assigned_days].d) AS [end_date], MIN([groups_assigned_days].[Employee]) AS Employee
    FROM [groups_assigned_days] 
    GROUP BY [groups_assigned_days].g
) 
SELECT [compact_groups].[start_date], [compact_groups].[end_date], [compact_groups].[Employee] 
FROM [compact_groups] 
ORDER BY [compact_groups].[start_date];
```

That gives the output:

| start_date | end_date | Employee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-14 | ABc |
| 2023-01-15 | 2023-05-01 | CBa |
| 2023-05-02 | 2023-12-31 | ABc |

For the other case, you just have to change the SQL so that the caseid is 2:

```sql
;WITH digits AS (
    SELECT I FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) AS digits(I)
), integers AS (
    SELECT D1.I + 10 * D2.I + 100*D3.I + 1000*D4.I + 10000*D5.I AS I
    FROM [digits] AS D1 CROSS JOIN [digits] AS D2 CROSS JOIN [digits] AS D3 
    CROSS JOIN [digits] AS D4 CROSS JOIN [digits] AS D5
), all_employee_dates AS (
    SELECT [startDate] AS d, [Employee] FROM [#ranges] WHERE [caseId] = 2
    UNION 
    SELECT [EndDate] AS d, [Employee] FROM [#ranges] WHERE [caseId] = 2
), min_and_max_dates AS (
    SELECT MIN(d) AS min_date, MAX(d) AS max_date FROM all_employee_dates 
), [days] AS (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, integers.I, [min_and_max_dates].[min_date]) AS d
    FROM [min_and_max_dates] CROSS JOIN [integers] 
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, integers.I, [min_and_max_dates].[min_date]) <= [min_and_max_dates].[max_date]
), calendar AS (
    SELECT [d].[d], [r].[caseId], [r].[startDate], [r].[endDate], [r].[Employee], DATEDIFF(DAY, r.[startDate], r.[endDate]) AS [days]
    FROM [days] AS d
    INNER JOIN [#ranges] AS r ON d.[d] BETWEEN r.[startDate] AND r.[endDate] AND r.[caseId] = 2
), prioritized_calendar AS ( 
    SELECT [calendar].[d],
           [calendar].[caseId],
           [calendar].[startDate],
           [calendar].[endDate],
           [calendar].[Employee],
           [calendar].[days], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [calendar].[d] ORDER BY [calendar].[days]) AS rn 
    FROM [calendar] 
), assigned_days AS (
    SELECT [prioritized_calendar].[d], [prioritized_calendar].[Employee]
    FROM [prioritized_calendar] 
    WHERE rn = 1 
), groups_assigned_days AS (
    SELECT [assigned_days].[d], [assigned_days].[Employee], 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [assigned_days].[Employee] ORDER BY [assigned_days].[d]), [assigned_days].[d]) AS g
    FROM [assigned_days] 
), compact_groups AS (
    SELECT MIN([groups_assigned_days].d) AS [start_date], MAX([groups_assigned_days].d) AS [end_date], MIN([groups_assigned_days].[Employee]) AS Employee
    FROM [groups_assigned_days] 
    GROUP BY [groups_assigned_days].g
) 
SELECT [compact_groups].[start_date], [compact_groups].[end_date], [compact_groups].[Employee] 
FROM [compact_groups] 
ORDER BY [compact_groups].[start_date];
```

That gives the output:

| start_date | end_date | Employee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-14 | ABc |
| 2023-01-15 | 2023-03-01 | DEf |
| 2023-03-02 | 2023-05-01 | ABc |
| 2023-05-02 | 2023-12-31 | GHi |

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I will looking into it tomorrow.